# не получается запустить apache2

Tags: apache2

> service apache2 start
>   Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
>   See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> > Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
> >           Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
> >           turn off this notice.
> >     No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.

Comment: Вы ввели команды, которые вам рекомендовали?

Comment: @vp_arth да скинуть то что они отобразили

Comment: Желательно добавить в вопрос

Comment: @vp_arth добавил картинкой

Comment: вы уверены, что у вас apache установился без ошибок?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman вроде да,попробую переустановить тогда

Comment: `127` обычно значит, что сервис не смог выполнить команду. Т.е. сервер, о котором он знает лежит где-то не там.

Comment: короче должен быть `/usr/sbin/apache2`, а его нет. Можно попробовать `whereis apache2` посмотреть.

Comment: @vp_arth а почему он его там ищет? он же в etc должен быть,проблема еще актуальна

Comment: Бинарники в etc? Там кроме конфигов, обычно ничего нет. Переустановка не помогла?

Comment: @vp_arth не не помогла он вот так вот ищет 
apache2: /etc/apache2  /usr/share/apache2
 пару раз заново ставил